# TextBox Подсказка

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, textbox

Есть главное окно и там можно добавить: фамилию, имя, возраст и т.д. Как сделать, чтобы на заднем плане textBox выводились слова "Фамилия","Имя","Возраст" немного сероватого цвета и при нажатии на textBox этот текст исчезает(т.е. не пришлось бы его удалять)

---

- Так было:

> [image: Вот так было]

- Так стало:

> [image: Вот так стало]

Comment: WPF или WinForms?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В WinForms это решается созданием класса-наследника от `TextBox`, отправлающего самому себе сообщение [`EM_SETCUEBANNER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class CueTextBox : TextBox
{
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string Cue
    {
        get { return mCue; }
        set { mCue = value; updateCue(); }
    }

    private void updateCue()
    {
        if (this.IsHandleCreated && mCue != null)
        {
            SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x1501, (IntPtr)1, mCue);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        updateCue();
    }
    private string mCue;

    // PInvoke
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, string lp);
}
```

Добавляете этот класс в проект, компилируете, потом бросаете `CueTextBox` из Toolbox на форму и задаете свойство `Cue`. В остальном он ведет себя так же, как стандартный `TextBox`.

---

В WPF Watermark делается обычным `TextBlock` поверх текстбокса + `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` с проверкой на пустоту текста:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkBackground" Color="White" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkForeground" Color="LightSteelBlue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkBorder" Color="Indigo" />

        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />

        <Style x:Key="EntryFieldStyle" TargetType="Grid" >
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource brushWatermarkBackground}" Style="{StaticResource EntryFieldStyle}" >
            <TextBlock Margin="5,2" Text="This prompt dissappears as you type..." Foreground="{StaticResource brushWatermarkForeground}"
                       Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtUserEntry, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <TextBox Name="txtUserEntry" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brushWatermarkBorder}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

<sub>код для WPF взят с [Watermark / hint text / placeholder TextBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-placeholder-textbox-in-wpf)</sub>

Comment: Сделал с этим кодом, но столкнулся с ситуацией. Если стоит свойство ReadOnly - подсказка не отображается. А хотелось бы. Как бы это дело перехватить?