# Насколько верное решение placeholder textbox c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, инспекция-кода

Искал в интернете как сделать placeholder для TextBox но не нашел компактного кода и решил изобрести еще один велосипед.

На форме есть textbox в свойствах стоит Text = "Placeholder Text" и Tag = "Placeholder Text", далее вешаю обработчик событий

Определяем цвета placeholder'a

```
Color LeaveColor = Color.FromArgb(160, 160, 160);
Color EnterColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);


private void txt_kontrIn_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txt_kontrIn.Text == "")
    {
        txt_kontrIn.Text = (string)txt_kontrIn.Tag;
        txt_kontrIn.ForeColor = LeaveColor;
    }
}
```

и

```
private void txt_kontrIn_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(txt_kontrIn.Text == (string)txt_kontrIn.Tag)
    {
        txt_kontrIn.Text = "";
        txt_kontrIn.ForeColor = EnterColor;
    }
}
```

Насколько верно это решение и можно ли этот код еще сократить?

P.s. на форме много текстбоксов.

Comment: Если юзер введет "Placeholder Text", то текст исчезнет =)

Comment: @Raider не введет =) т.к. для каждого текстбокса свой текст будет

Comment: Они что ReadOnly?

Comment: @Raider нет, большую часть данных пользователь будет выбирать из подсказок

Comment: @Raider на форме порядка 20 текстбоксов и для каждого вводить значение что-то не очень охота

Comment: Нашел простое решение http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493592/textbox-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

> на форме много текстбоксов.

Сделай класс-наследник текстбокса, который будет добавлять placeholder. Его и используй.

> Насколько верно это решение

Лучше сохранять отдельный флаг, пустое ли поле. Если пустое, то подменять как сейчас, если нет, то не трогать. Это позволит пользователю вводить текст, совпадающий с плейсхолдером.

> можно ли этот код еще сократить?

Перестать копипастить код и сделать класс, инкапсулирующий соответствующую логику.