# Как добавить TextBox с "одноразовой" подсказкой в C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493592/textbox-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0) увидел годное решение для реализации подсказки в TextBox. Но есть проблема. Изначально (добавил в конструктор) поле показывает подсказку Null. То есть при добавлении строки строки в базу данных значение из этого поля будет никаким - Null. Но я хочу чтобы при вводе любого значения и удаления этого значения подсказка не возвращалась. И в базу данных пойдет не никакое значение, а пустая строка "". Как поправить класс, чтобы подсказка была "одноразовая"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то тишина в ответах. Своими культяпками вот так сделал:

```
class CueTextBox : TextBox
{
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string Cue
    {
        get { return mCue; }
        set { mCue = value; updateCue(); }
    }

    public CueTextBox()
        : base()
    {
        this.Cue = "Null";
        this.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(OnChange);

    }

    private void updateCue()
    {
        if (this.IsHandleCreated && mCue != null)
        {
            SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x1501, (IntPtr)1, mCue);
        }
    }

    void OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cue = "";
    }
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete && this.Text == "")
            this.Cue = "Null";
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        updateCue();
    }
    private string mCue;

    // PInvoke
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, string lp);
}
```